# Consulta con laravel APIrest con las solicitudes HTTP

Tags: laravel

Estoy usando mysql como db, cargue un par de datos, dentro tengo una tabla llamada contactos.. Quiero hacer lo siguiente : http://localhost/project-test/public/api/contactos/buscar?name=eric&surname=almendras, buscar al contacto de nombre eric y apellido almendras y que me devuelva el registro..

en laravel tengo mi controler siguiente:

```
public function buscar(Request $request){
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $surname = $request->input('surname');

    $contacto = Contacto::where([
       'name' => $name,
       'surname' => $surname
    ])->get();

    return $contacto;
}
```

y en la carpeta la siguiente route (api.php):

Route::get('buscar/{name}/{surname}','ContactosController@buscar');

entonces cuando hago la solicitud http://localhost/project-test/public/api/contactos/buscar?name=eric&surname=almendras, me devuelve un array vacio y no el registro del contacto eric..
intente hacer el siguiente controller:

```
public function buscar(Request $request){
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $surname = $request->input('surname');

    $contacto = Contacto::where([
       'name' => $name,
       'surname' => $surname
    ])->get();

    return $contacto;
}
```

y de todas formas sigue devolviendo un array vacio.. estoy usando laravel 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas usando mal dos cosas:

1. Los parámetros de rutas
2. La instancia de la solicitud `Request`

Si tienes una ruta como

```php
Route::get('buscar/{name}/{surname}','ContactosController@buscar');
```

Debes pasar algo como:

```html
http://localhost/project-test/public/api/contactos/buscar/eric/almendras
```

Porque al pasarlos como:

```html
http://localhost/project-test/public/api/contactos/buscar?name=eric&surname=almendras
```

Estas pasando esos parámetros como [Query String](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) o **Parámetros de cadena de consulta**

En caso de querer recuperar esos parame **Parámetros de cadena de consulta** tendrias que hacerlo así:

```php
public function buscar(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->query('name');
    $surname = $request->query('surname');
}
```

Como lo dice en la documentación de **Laravel** [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string)

##### NOTA

Por cierto, creo que lo que dijo @porloscerrosΨ es muy interesante, tu **url** es algo extraña; al ejecutar el comando `php artisan serve` para desplegar el servidor local de desarrollo, esta ruta quedaría en  algo como

```html
http://localhost:8000/api/contactos/buscar
```

Ya que esto despliega un servidor de php en el cual todos las solicitudes son despachadas a el archivo `public/index.php` y manejadas por el **sistema de rutas**

En caso de estar en producción o montado en un servidor (como por ejemplo **Apache**), debería estar configurado de la misma manera, atendiendo todas las solicitudes a ese único archivo `index.php`